# Javascript object executor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve the following question. But still now I couldn't. Can anyone please help me to solve the question?

[image]

I've done the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Test Solution</title>
   </head>
<body>

    <h1>Solution 2</h1>

    <p id="demo"> </p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var executor = {
    "string": function (value) { return "" + value; },
    "number": function (value) { return 1 + parseInt(value, 10); },   
    run     : function (data) {

    // split the string and remove whitespaces
    var str_array = data.split(/\s*,\s*/);

    for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {

        console.log(str_array[i]);

        if (typeof str_array[i] === "function") {
            console.log('function');
        }           

    }       
        returnData = executor.string(data);
        return returnData;
    }
};
var input = "foo,,bar,2,string(hi),string(5)";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = executor.run(input);
</script>
</body>
```

Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: Once you split by commas, you need to check if the item contains parentheses. If it does, it means it's a "function". From there you need to "parse" the function, get the name and what the parameter is. Then execute the function and add it to the output. If the item doesn't contain parentheses, then just add it as it stands.

Comment: We don't just write code for you.  Can you explain (in your question) where you are stuck in your implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure am I in right way. If so, now I'm stuck in to check if this string is a function or not. The current check is not working.

Comment: `typeof` will always be `"string"`, since splitting a string returns an array of strings. `typeof str_array[i]` doesn't check whether the string contains the name of a function.

Comment: You need to check whether `str_array[i]` contains `()`. Remove that from the name, and then check whether `typeof executor[name] == "function"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in the comments the initial problem is in checking for function. Since the value will have `()`, you need to extract the function name from the string then check whether it exists.

```js
var executor = {
  "string": function(value) {
    return "" + value;
  },
  "number": function(value) {
    return 1 + parseInt(value, 10);
  },
  rootOf: function(value) {
    return Math.sqrt(value);
  },
  run: function(data) {

    // split the string and remove whitespaces
    var str_array = data.split(/\s*,\s*/);

    var result = str_array.map(function(value) {
      var fnparts = value.match(/(.*)\((.*)\)/)
      if (fnparts && fnparts.length == 3) { //if function
        try {
          if (typeof executor[fnparts[1]] == 'function') { //check whether the function exists in the executor
            if (fnparts[2].trim()) { //if there are parameters then pass them to the function
              return executor[fnparts[1]].apply(window, fnparts[2].split(/\s*,\s*/))
            } else { //else just call the function
              return executor[fnparts[1]]();
            }
          } else {
            return 'error';
          }
        } catch (e) {
          return 'error';
        }
      } else { //if it is not a function then call the string/number function
        if (/^\d+$/.test(value)) {
          return executor.number(value);
        } else {
          return executor.string(value);
        }
        return value;
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
};
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = executor.run("foo,,bar,2,string(hi),string(5)");
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = executor.run("adf, rootOf(9)");
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = executor.run("foo,,bar,2,string(hi),string(5)");
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = executor.run("foo,,bar,2,string(hi),string(5)");
```

```html
<h1>Solution 2</h1>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you boss. You are a genius. But I've another problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r82ihq7p033zwg3/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-04%20at%202.22.17%20PM.png?dl=0

I can do the sum extension. But I'm worried how can I retrieve POST & GET values.